# Scroll the internal child div

Tags: jquery, css, html, scroll

I have created a div there are two childs of that div one is `ul` and other is a `div` I want to scroll the elements of that internal div and font to fix the `ul`. I can not add any other `div` around the internal `div`

**Code**

```
<div style="width: 200px; overflow-x: auto; ">
<ul>
    <li>Some data</li>
    <li>some more data </li>
</ul>
<div style="height: 70px; width: 500px">
    <img src="http://www.fiveriverstech.com/wp-content/themes/fiverivers/images/about_s.jpg">
    <img src="http://www.fiveriverstech.com/wp-content/themes/fiverivers/images/about_s.jpg">
    <img src="http://www.fiveriverstech.com/wp-content/themes/fiverivers/images/about_s.jpg">
    <img src="http://www.fiveriverstech.com/wp-content/themes/fiverivers/images/about_s.jpg">
    <img src="http://www.fiveriverstech.com/wp-content/themes/fiverivers/images/about_s.jpg">
    <img src="http://www.fiveriverstech.com/wp-content/themes/fiverivers/images/about_s.jpg">
    <img src="http://www.fiveriverstech.com/wp-content/themes/fiverivers/images/about_s.jpg">
    <img src="http://www.fiveriverstech.com/wp-content/themes/fiverivers/images/about_s.jpg">
</div>
</div>​
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ranasaani/57wdH/81/)**

Comment: something like this http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/57wdH/83/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div style="width: 150px; overflow-x: auto;position:relative ">
    <ul style="position:fixed">
        <li>Some data</li>
        <li>some more data </li>
    </ul>
    <div style="height: 100px; width: 500px;margin-top:60px">
        <img src="http://www.fiveriverstech.com/wp-content/themes/fiverivers/images/about_s.jpg">
        <img src="http://www.fiveriverstech.com/wp-content/themes/fiverivers/images/about_s.jpg">
        <img src="http://www.fiveriverstech.com/wp-content/themes/fiverivers/images/about_s.jpg">
        <img src="http://www.fiveriverstech.com/wp-content/themes/fiverivers/images/about_s.jpg">
        <img src="http://www.fiveriverstech.com/wp-content/themes/fiverivers/images/about_s.jpg">
        <img src="http://www.fiveriverstech.com/wp-content/themes/fiverivers/images/about_s.jpg">
        <img src="http://www.fiveriverstech.com/wp-content/themes/fiverivers/images/about_s.jpg">
        <img src="http://www.fiveriverstech.com/wp-content/themes/fiverivers/images/about_s.jpg">
</div>
</div>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/57wdH/88/)

Comment: I already said in question. I cannot add any other div around the internal div. Please tell me the another solution

Answer (score 0):

Hi Rana check it i have played within your code the help of **white-space:nowrap;** proptery.
This white space property will continue our inline elements in the horizontal way....

**nowrap** is the value of proptery **white-space** and this nowwrap value suppresses all line breaks in the element.

```
<div style="width: 250px; border:1px solid red; ">
    <ul>
        <li>Some data</li>
        <li>some more data </li>
    </ul>
  <div style="border:1px solid black;width:150px;height:70px;overflow-y:hidden;overflow-x:scroll; white-space:nowrap;">

        <img src="http://www.fiveriverstech.com/wp-content/themes/fiverivers/images/about_s.jpg">
        <img src="http://www.fiveriverstech.com/wp-content/themes/fiverivers/images/about_s.jpg">
        <img src="http://www.fiveriverstech.com/wp-content/themes/fiverivers/images/about_s.jpg">
        <img src="http://www.fiveriverstech.com/wp-content/themes/fiverivers/images/about_s.jpg">
        <img src="http://www.fiveriverstech.com/wp-content/themes/fiverivers/images/about_s.jpg">
        <img src="http://www.fiveriverstech.com/wp-content/themes/fiverivers/images/about_s.jpg">
        <img src="http://www.fiveriverstech.com/wp-content/themes/fiverivers/images/about_s.jpg">
        <img src="http://www.fiveriverstech.com/wp-content/themes/fiverivers/images/about_s.jpg">

</div>
</div>
```

see the demo :- http://jsbin.com/ovazol/edit#html,live